# Chiral Landau's fermi liquid theory in 3+1D

Tags: condensed-matter

In standard LFL theory, the effect mass of quasiparticle is different from the composite Fermion's mass. It seems that this is no longer true in Chiral case (e.g. a finite density system with interacting massless left handed fermions)? 
What is Landau's FL theory for chiral Fermions? 
Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking why the masslessness is preserved at low energies?

Comment: Is it still massless at low energy and why?

Comment: What do you mean by 3+1D ? There are systems in 1D with chiral fermions that can be studied at low energies. In that case it is not possible to use Fermi liquid theory and we don't introduce quasiparticles. Are you looking for 3D models especially or any problem involving chiral fermions ?

Comment: 3+1D means 3 spatial dimensions and 1 time dimensions, i.e. the space-time we are living.